# Create Dictionary from List of Lists from CSV file - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have an example csv file with header values: Fruit, Size, Color:

```
Fruit  Size  Color
Apple  5     Red 
Apple  6     Green
Pear   4     Green
```

I want to create a dictionary where I can look up the 'Fruit' and get the 'Size' and 'Color'.

My Code:

```
import csv
new_dict = {}
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    if row[0] in new_dict:
      new_dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
      new_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
print new_dict
```

The output I'm expecting to see when I print new_dict is:

```
{'Apple': ['5', 'Red'],['6', 'Green'], 'Pear': ['4', 'Green'] }
```

or possibly (not really sure how this works with multiple values with same key)

```
{'Apple': [['5', 'Red'],['6', 'Green']], 'Pear': ['4', 'Green'] }
```

But what I'm actually getting looks like:

```
{'Apple': ['5', 'Red', ['6', 'Green']], 'Pear': ['4', 'Green'] }
```

The problem is `['5', 'Red', ['6', 'Green']]`, where the 2nd Apple item to be added is inside the list of the first Apple item.

---

Basically, I want to be able to type: `new_dict["Apple"]` and return all of lists with the key "Apple".

So how do I properly build my dictionary to include multiple values that have the same key? and avoid additional values from being put inside the list of the first value added for that key? ("Apple" in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your data points come in pairs, you need to keep them that way together in a list. This fixes the problem:

`new_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]` change to `new_dict[row[0]] = [row[1:]]`

This will produce:

```
{'Apple': [['5', 'Red'], ['6', 'Green']], 'Pear': [['4', 'Green']] }
```

Alternatively, you can make them as tuples which is more suitable for your problem because they are fixed size:

`.append(tuple(row[1:]))` and `new_dict[row[0]] = [tuple(row[1:])]`

This will produce:

```
{'Apple': [('5', 'Red'), ('6', 'Green')], 'Pear': [('4', 'Green')] }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I get the following error when I try with tuples.  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @brno792 Ah, sorry, repeated your mistake :) Be sure to have the single element as a list of one tuple rather than just a tuple. See the fixed part `new_dict[row[0]] = [tuple(row[1:])]` instead of `new_dict[row[0]] = tuple(row[1:])`